# How to define a function with multiple names

Tags: c, gcc, alias

I'd like to declare the following function with multiple names:

```
static __inline__ int square(int i) {
  return i * i;
}
```

It only has to work with GCC 4.x (for some useful value of x)

I've tried `__asm__`, but it works for non-static functions only, so this doesn't work:

```
static __inline__ int square2(int i) __asm__("square");
```

I've tried `alias`, but it prevents the call to `square2` from being inlined, but I want inlining for both `square` and `square2`, equivalently.

```
static __inline__ int square2(int i) __attribute__((alias("square2")));
```

I've tried a macro, but that prevents me from using independent local variables named `square` and `square2` in other unrelated functions. So I can't accept this:

```
#define square2 square
```

I know about writing another call, but I don't like it, because it's one more indirection for the optimizer, and it may prevent inlining in some complicated case:

```
static __inline__ int square2(int i) { return square(i); }
```

Is there another solution?

Comment: Inline functions have been inlined in their call site. So they don't have names (unless you force the compiler to not inline them, e.g. by taking their address).

Comment: Why not use the "always inline" attribute on a static implementation function that's called only from the multiple-named functions (square, square2)? There should be no extra layer of indirection in that case.

Comment: I'm curious about the last alternative (simply wrapping the first call). Does it actually inline both?

Comment: Curious, why do you want multiple names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your "real" code has a more complicated function than a single statement? Else the obvious choice is to repeat the definition with the second name.

You could make it a macro, of course:

```
#define SQUARE_BODY(a) return (a) * (a);

static inline square(int x)
{
  SQUARE_BODY(x);
}

static inline square2(int x)
{
  SQUARE_BODY(x);
}
```

Of course you can fold more of the function definitions into the macro, but I think that having it only be the body part makes the rest of the code clearer.